# sending a group message on my galaxy s3

Tags: sms, mms

When I send a group message on my galaxy s3 software 4.3 other people in the group message receive the message as an individual message. How do I fix this so that all the people in message receive it as a group message.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using Whatsapp messenger, it deals with group messages much better than using SMS.

Using Whatsapp everyone can reply to a message that you've sent and all participants can see each other's replies.

You can download it from here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

Also remember all the recipients of a group message can also see every person you add to the conversation as well as their phone numbers. Like (1990clb) says try a messaging app meant for group mssg. , even google voice/hangouts has a great app that can include a couple (**or**) your entire contact list. I guess to remind them all about your upcoming surprise birthday party... Also allows u to video chat or make a call with the same group of ppl if texting becomes too confusing for your grandmother.